# Ubuntu 22.04 dark theme from command line

Tags: themes, 22.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2 + WSLg.

After the upgrade everything has Light Theme.

How do I change to dark theme from command line in ubuntu 22.04 ?

Answer (score 5):

Shell only:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme prefer-dark
```

Synced desktop

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark # Legacy apps, can specify an accent such as Yaru-olive-dark
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark # new apps
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme # if changed above
```

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/Initiatives/-/wikis/Dark-Style-Preference)

seems to work in my installation.

Command line I use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
```

Comment: Same here. I didn't need to run the other commands in mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

terminal -> preferences:

on the left site you should have your profile already created. Most probably name of your profile will be "unnamed" etc but click it. Select "Colours" and then try to find some dark theme from prepared templates or create your own configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved reinstalling the os.had some issues cause i installed google chrome with sudo apt get instead of dpkg. This way all the dependences were installed, included some kde desktop stuffs that conflicted with gnome and theme settings. .

Answer (score 0):

I tested that script and it worked very well on Ubuntu 22.04

In terminal, type `cd ~/`

To turn **DARK** mode on:

1. Create a batch file with any convenient name `touch switchDarkTheme.sh`
2. Change permission to be executable via `chmod +x switchDarkTheme.sh`
3. Edit the file via `nano switchDarkTheme.sh`
4. Paste the following code

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme prefer-dark
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru-dark
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
   ```
5. Save, close and execute from terminal via `./switchDarkTheme.sh`

To turn **LIGHT** mode on:

1. Create a batch file with any convenient name `touch switchLightTheme.sh`
2. Change permission to be executable via `chmod +x switchLightTheme.sh`
3. Edit the file via `nano switchLightTheme.sh`
4. Paste the following code

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.ubuntu color-scheme prefer-light
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme Yaru
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
   ```
5. Save, close and execute from terminal via `./switchLightTheme.sh`

For automating the switch based on a manual time, you can use `crontab`. Let's say you want to switch light mode at **5am** and dark mode at **7pm**, you can simply add the below lines after running the `crontab -e` command

`0 5 * * * /home/{whoami}/switchLightTheme.sh` #amend the path based on your file location.

`0 19 * * * /home/{whoami}/switchDarkTheme.sh` #amend the path based on your file location.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue too, because command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-sheme prefer-dark
```

didn't work for me. When I was trying to get which GTK theme setting is used with this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
```

It returned 'Adwaita', because Adwaita is the default GTK theme for GNOME. It has both a light and a dark version so I managed to resolve it by other command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'
```

What is more I found out that

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark
```

is a relatively new addition and is meant to work with GTK4 and applications that support the color-scheme setting. Not all applications will respond to the color-scheme setting, especially if they are using GTK3 or earlier.
Hope it helps!